# How to convert implementors on one interface into another?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble finding a way to do this in a way that doesn't seem wrong, given the following

```
public interface IType {}
public interface IMode {}

public interface Factory<T extends IType> {
   IMode get(T o);

   Class<T> getIType();
}
```

I have the above interfaces and a large list on classes the implement both `IType` and `IMode` with corresponding factories.

I need to be able to convert from one to the other, for example,

```
public class A implements IType {}
public class One implements IMode {}

public class AToOne implements Factory<A> {
    public IMode get(A o){
       return new One();
    }

    public Class<A> getIType(){
       return A.class;
    }
}
```

**Given that there is a 1 to 1 mapping of these classes**, ie for every concrete `IType` there is one and only one concrete `IMode` with corresponding factory, **how would I go about converting a list of `IType`s to a list of `IMode`s?**

ie.

```
private List<Factory<? extends IType>> factoryList;

public List<IMode> getConversions(List<? extends IType> types){
    ???
}
```

---

My first try did not go so well,

```
//Fill this using the getIType() method from each factory
Map<Class<IType>, Factory<? extends IType>> factoryList = new HashMap<Class<IType>, Factory<? extends IType>>();

 public List<IMode> getConversions(List<IType> types){
    List<IMode> modes = new ArrayList<IMode>();

    for(IType type : types){
        //Derp
        Factory<? extends IType> factory = factoryList.get(type.getClass());
        //Error
        factory.get(factory.getIType().cast(type));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 The method get(capture#12-of ? extends IType) in the type
 Factory<capture#12-of ? extends IType>
 is not applicable for the arguments (capture#14-of ? extends IType)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The general idea behind your approach seems fine to me.

Comment: @Voo In the attempt outlined above, `type.getClass()` is returning the concrete class which won't match what I put in the map, and then I don't know how to cast the input to the factory that I did get, as there is no guarantee they are the same. What I wrote does not compile.

Comment: Ah so your problem isn't the general design approach, but the generics part. That should be easy to fix up, let me try that :)

Comment: Yeah you just need a class-to-instance map with a wrapping generic  accessor to handle unchecked casts. Take it away @Voo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, you just need to use a generic helper method to access the map, which performs an unchecked cast from `Factory<? extends IType>` to a `Factory<T>` where `T` matches the type of what's passed in:

```
Map<Class<? extends IType>, Factory<? extends IType>> factoryList =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends IType>, Factory<? extends IType>>();

private <T extends IType> IMode convert(T iType) {
    //unchecked cast - implementation must guarantee map holds correct data
    Factory<T> factory = (Factory<T>)factoryList.get(iType.getClass());
    //then convert
    return factory.get(iType);
}
```

You can call this helper method from the loop:

```
public List<IMode> getConversions(List<IType> types) {
    List<IMode> modes = new ArrayList<IMode>(types.size());
    for (IType type : types) {
        IMode iMode = convert(type);
        modes.add(iMode);
    }
    return modes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing, I also needed to loop through all the declared classes of my IType as `getClass` returned the concrete class not the interface. Man does it feel dirty.

Comment: Isn't the concrete class what you want though? That's what's being used as the key in the map of factories.

Comment: Oops yeah, my actual code is more complex and I have subclasses extending my concrete `IMode` classes. just details, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is the following:

```
interface IFoo {
}

interface IBar {
}

private static class Foo implements IFoo {
}

private static class Bar implements IBar {
}

interface IFoo2IBarConverter<B extends IBar, F extends IFoo> {
    B convert(F foo);
}

private static class Foo2BarConverter implements IFoo2IBarConverter<Bar, Foo> {
    public Bar convert(Foo foo) {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

private static class IFoo2IBarFactory {
    private static HashMap<Class<? extends IFoo>, IFoo2IBarConverter<? extends IBar, ? extends IFoo>> converters = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        converters.put(Foo.class, new Foo2BarConverter());
    }

    public static<F extends IFoo, B extends IBar> B convert(F foo) {
        // ugly unchecked cast here
        IFoo2IBarConverter<B, F> converter = (IFoo2IBarConverter<B, F>) converters.get(foo.getClass());
        return converter.convert(foo);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    IBar bar = IFoo2IBarFactory.convert(foo);
}
```

You just take a HashMap that maps a specific class that's a subtype of `IFoo` to some converter interface. The converter takes the `IFoo` instance and converts it into a `IBar`.. actually into the specific classes we want. Sadly we get an ugly cast in `IFoo2IBarFactory.convert()` and I don't think there's any way to avoid that one. Still at least it's only in one localized position and with the right comment and a SuppressWarning you can live with it, I'd think

Comment: I'm not sure you need the IFoo2IBarConverter interface.  Just have the Class corresponding to IBar and use it to cast.  e.g.  `Class<Bar> clazz = converters.get(foo); return clazz.cast(foo);`

Comment: @user949300 Not sure I follow. Yes you can by without the interface by using raw objects and using a large switch inside `convert`, but that's *extremely* ugly and doesn't win us anything. After your edit: You can call static methods on the class object? Didn't know that, I'd still go with the split solution - seems cleaner.

Comment: `B extends IBar` should not be declared for `convert` because the caller decides what that is without restriction, which could easily lead to heap pollution. That method should just return `IBar`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Voo, won't this require me to call a different method for each type? That's not really better than just a long if else block with `instanceof`'s

Comment: @Andrew Not sure I can follow. Yes you do have to define a `IFoo2IBarConverter` for every conversion you want, because how would we know how to convert arbitrary classes to another. But other than that the rest of the code is generic and works with dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Paul I don't see the problem, in the worst case we get `B=IBar` I'd think which isn't any worse than just returning `IBar` to begin with. But if we need a more specific return type this allows us to easily specify it without any overhead.

Comment: `how would we know how to convert arbitrary classes to another` That's the crux of my whole question I guess, I was looking for a way to do just that. Which unfortunately requires an unchecked conversion at some point. **I** know it will convert, but there is not way to programmatically enforce that.

Comment: @Andrew Which is why we put the unchecked cast into a single wrapper method and don't have the several `IFoo2IBarConverter` deal with it. Java's typesystem isn't strong enough to specify this, so we'll always need the one cast. But having it encapsulated in a single method and well documented is the best approach there. To convert a whole list of objects you just iterate through them and call convert on each one, no cast there.

Comment: No, in the worst case the caller specifies `<Foo, SteelBar>` where `SteelBar` also implements `IBar` but `Foo.class` actually maps to a `Foo2BarConverter` (rather than a `Foo2SteelBarConverter`). This will cause heap polution and a `ClassCastException` at some later time.

Comment: @Paul Ok yep if you want to crash your program by design you can do that, but why oh why would anyone do that? But true it makes it less safe.

Comment: Why do people write bugs into their code? :) If you wanted to safely make the return type generic too, instead of just `IBar`, the converter map would need to be keyed on something like `Pair<Class<? extends IFoo>, Class<? extends IBar>>`.

Comment: @Paul Yeah true enough. Not sure I see how your typesafe solution would work though, I'll have to think that through in some quiet hour.